# Is it bad to use user name as primary key in database design?

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key, unique-key

I was told by a friend:

> What unique key do you use? I hope you
>   are not saving the entire user name
>   --- this will use up too much table space! Assign an unique userID to each
>   (unique) userNAME and save this userID
>   (should be INTEGER UNSIGNED
>   auto_increment  or  BIGINT UNSIGNED
>   auto_increment). Don't forget to
>   create a reference
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES
>   `usertable` (`userID`) in all tables
>   using the userID.

Is the above statement correct? Why or why not?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think he is right ( for the wrong reason) because primary key cannot change, but `username` can change. So you should use `userid` because it wouldn't change.

Comment: The primary key cannot change.  Or it isn't "primary".  The key should be system-assigned, to guarantee that it can never change.  Other fields (like name) can have unique indexes, but cannot be a primary key -- by definition.

Comment: The application specifies some field as primary key and thus non changing. The application can later change, making a field originally defined as unique and non changing, to allow duplicates or to change, which is the point here.

Comment: It's true too for join table? In other words, should I create ID for every entry in join table because the combination of primary keys can change?

Answer (score 21):

He is right for the wrong reasons. The table space is secondary to the fact that your app might later mandate that usernames can be changed or even stop being unique (you could envision an application where unique usernames are not required, like Stack Overflow) and thus your app would need major refactoring and data migration instead of a light change in the other (integer PK) case.