# PHP login with wrong password still works

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a login page with PHP and a MySQL database. Everything works fine except when I login with the right username and wrong password it still sends me to the logged in page and doesn't keep me on the login page.

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$pass = md5($pass);

$connect = mysql_connect("$host", "$ad_user", "$ad_pass") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$db = mysql_select_db("$db", $connect) or die("Could not select examples");

$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user'" or die("error query");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$p = mysql_fetch_array($result);
If($count == 1){
    If($p['password'] == $pass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        header('Location: //members.polydodo.com');
    }else{
        header('Location: ../login.php?error');
    }
}else{
    header('Location: ../login.php?error');
}

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

I can't see any mistakes in this and I've double checked orders of password encryption, etc. already. Using the wrong username redirects to the error page and doesn't log me in but it logs me in with the right username regardless of the password.

P.S. I am aware of MySQLi and PDO but have't had time to look into that yet so I'm sticking with standard MySQL until I do.

Comment: First of all, please stop using MySQL and switch to MySQLi || PDO. Read note, MySQLi functions/methods are almost identical to MySQL ones, I bet for most php scripts you could just run a Find+Replace for mysql_ to mysqli_, but OOB is better again. Second of all, please stop using MD5 for a SHA512 or other better hash type, and look into password salting.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection!** So stop with the lame excuses about not having the time to look into something that prevents the basic vulnerability in your code.

Comment: So you are allowing username duplicates ?

Answer (score 4):

problem is in below line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user'" or die("error query");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

change it to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE :**

also use password for authentication directly in the query like

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Note:** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Use password field as well.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'" or die("error query");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//$p = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($count == 1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        header('Location: //members.polydodo.com');
}else{
    header('Location: ../login.php?error');
}
```

Try to pass both the values in query. You dont need to match it after

Comment: I tried that to start off with and it isn't working. Would the fact that I'm using the username as the primary key in the database have anything to do with it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try using that code. Username must be unique if you want

Comment: The code you posted is what I started off with and couldn't get to work before making it a bit complicated. Also the username column is set to unique to avoid duplicates and there is only one row at the moment.

Comment: @rmalex it should be that you create a user_id as your primary key and unique key. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825613/is-it-bad-to-use-user-name-as-primary-key-in-database-design

Comment: @TBI I have just discovered that regardless of the password I enter it produces the exact same md5 hash.

Comment: @rmalex THAT'S THE REASON YOU SHOULD FREAKING DROP THE `mysql_*` API. You screwed up in your code in a way that would be impossible with PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: Also it would have prevented you that nasty mysql injection hole

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes I get it; change over to MySQLi, which I have every intention of doing but surely using MySQL wouldn't cause this issue?

Comment: I cannot see how MySQLi would solve a problem that appears to be nothing to do with the SQL (it might well fix other issues such as the sql injection potential). If the OPs script always generates the same MD5 for any password then that is a fault of their logic in dealing with the password and nothing to do with checking the database.

Comment: Thank you Kickstart. I solved it by removing the mysql_real_escape_string part as it resulted in all passwords producing the same MD5 hash.

Comment: @Kickstart with msqli *and* prepared statements OP didn't have to screw up using `mysql_real_escape_string` before having a connection (which is OPs problem and is clearly stated in both the offical documentation as well as an error message ios spit out when properly having error reporting enabled. Also a simple `var_dump` on the data should have told OP this.

Comment: Ah, if no connection it tries to make one & when testing on wamp that actually succeeded! Hence my confusion when testing it. @rmalex , the problem is that with no connection mysql_real_escape_string tries to make a connection to the database with no parameters (which in your case failed). With no connection it returns false. Hence you were trying to check a password which was the MD5 of false, irrespective of the password entered. Removing mysql_real_escape_string is NOT the solution. Move the connection before mysql_real_escape_string or switch to a parameterised query.

Comment: No the only answer is "a parameterised query" the above would still not fix the SQLi vulnerability.